# Why my S3 hostname/path always double? even try path_style: ture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I use fog-aws(1.2.0) and rails 5.1.1 and carrierwave 0.9.0.
here is my problem

```
Excon::Error::Socket (hostname "assets-xxxx-staging-xxxx-co.assets-lighthouse-staging-xxxx-co.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)):
```

and i tried `path_style`: true 
the error is `SignatureDoesNotMatch`, then i found the path wrong too.

```
:host          => "assets-xxxx-staging-xxxx-co.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"
  :local_address => "172.104.102.98"
  :local_port    => 42496
  :path          => "/assets-xxxx-staging-xxxx-co/assets-xxxx-staging-xxxx-co/uploads/image/file/677/14138703_1238894682828634_8829163820773300140_o.jpg"
  :port          => 443
  :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
```

Why always the double path...
What is going on? I have no idea about this....?
Please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my self !

First step, i move the bucket form Tokyo to Singapore.

Last step, i change bucket name to shorter (do not use full stop sign . ).

Just working....

Although i didnt not know which step let it work, i believe the first step has higher chance.

AWS has bug between difference religion before.

If you use fog-aws gem too. Its truly has a chance that the hostname will duplicate prefix the url, and this issue link might helpful.

https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/issues/228